# Swift Package Manager: How to load a UIViewController + xib pair like in a regular Xcode project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

In a regular iOS Xcode project, when you create a Cocoa touch file (`MyVC.swift`), you can also create an associated xib (`MyVC.xib`). Call `super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)` in the view controller, and then the outlets are ready to be used.

In this case, I'm attempting to port over code from my project, into a Swift Package, which will get reused across other projects. When in the Swift Package, I cannot find a way to load the xib for my view controller. After hooking everything up correctly, and calling `super.init(nibName:bundle:)`, the outlets are still always `nil` at the time of `viewDidLoad`.

Is this possible in a Swift Package? If so, how; if not, are there any go-to alternatives? This feels like a pretty standard use case.

Fwiw, I'm using swift-tools-version 5.3, and my platform is `.iOS(.v13)`

---

A variety of `init`s that I've tried:

- `super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)`
- `super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: .main)`
- `super.init(nibName: "\(Self.self)", bundle: .main)`
- `super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: .init(for: Self.self))`
- `super.init(nibName: "\(Self.self)", bundle: .init(for: Self.self))`

Comment: 1. Double check if both xib and controller are part of the same bundle, and correct 'module' is selected for controller / File's owner in the xib. 2. Try using actual name of the nib 3. try using directly the view controller name instead of `Self` to initialize the Bundle `.init(for:MyVC.self)` 4. try initializing your Bundle using bundle identifier of the library `.init(identifier: com.mycompany.myapp)`

Answer (score 13):

After hours of researching to no avail, I found the following [Swift forum proposal](https://forums.swift.org/t/draft-proposal-package-resources/29941), which led me to my answer:

`super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: .module)`

The "module" bundle is what I was looking for: It "Returns the resource bundle associated with the current Swift module."

After using this, my xibs/Storyboards loaded correctly.

Comment: I get the error `Type 'Bundle?' has no member 'module'`. Is this still the correct usage?

Comment: @Kyle You need to add your Xib first, then attempt to use `.module`. The `.module` becomes available automatically once Xcode detects a Xib in your package.